# Terminal shows ">" after running command

Tags: terminal

I am new to Mac Terminal. I am learning. After entering a command it gives me just that: `>`  What does it mean? What should I do now, how to continue or scape?

Here is the command I issued:

```
for file in *.txt; do echo mv "$file" "${file/#new/nou}”; done
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste the relevant part (the command you typed and the output) into the question?

Comment: @patrix: I try to learn how to change the name of many files. Just to test I tried: for file in *.txt; do echo mv "$file" "${file/#new/nou}”; done In this case I want to change a file name new-file.txt for nou-file.txt

Comment: Please click on `edit` below the text of your question and copy/paste the relevant part, as you've typed it, directly from Terminal into the text of the question to make sure we look at the same problem as you do.

Comment: It looks like the last quote may be "smart" when it should be straight.  Did I see another question about that here somewhere?

Comment: @Allan The quotes take care of the hash. But as Tom points out the last quote is wrong (assuming the OP copied from Terminal into the comment they wrote).

Comment: @Allan, There is nothing wrong with using the # sign in a command when it's applicable. See `${parameter/pattern/string}` under 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion in the BASH Reference Manual: "If pattern begins with ‘#’, it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of parameter." The issue is the smart-quote as mentioned by Tom Gewecke.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case, the problem is you are inputing a `”` character in your command after `nou}` (note, not a `"` but a `”`) .

The command should look like this:

`for file in *.txt; do echo mv "$file" "${file/#new/nou}"; done`

To break out of any ongoing command just press `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: Just for completion, after pressing `Ctrl+C` the command executed successfully.

Answer (score 2):

It means that you've entered something that leads the shell to believe the command is not complete, and you need to enter more text. A "\" character is most likely. Either finish your command or use Ctrl-C to break out of it.

Comment: It looks like the last quote may be "smart" when it should be straight. Did I see another question about that here somewhere?